# Django and south migration: unexpected field came out

Tags: django, django-south

I'm using Django 1.6 as a banckend and I'm using South for migration.
I have two tables, `Content` and `Channel`, I added a field `adress` in `Channel`:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
  adress = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=True)
```

and I added a `ForeignKey` in table `Content`:

```
class Content(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
  channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, null=True, blank=True)
```

When I run the command :

```
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
```

I got this:

```
 + Added field adress on myapp.Channel
 ? The field 'Content.adress' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
 ? Since you are removing this field, you MUST specify a default
 ? value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
 ?  1. Quit now.
 ?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
 ?  3. Disable the backwards migration by raising an exception; you can edit the migration to fix it later
 ? Please select a choice: Connection to v-atm-t3v closed by remote host.
```

Why do I have field `Content.adress`? I marked the `ForeignKey` as `null=True,blank=True` because I want it to be blank by default, how can I solve that? Thanks!

Comment: Did you remove a field called `adress` from `Content` model?

Comment: Yes I think so@ShangWang

Comment: So I deleted a field named `adress` how can I deal with that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is basically saying: You were having a field called `adress` in model `Content` before, and it's couldn't be null when you defined it(you don't have `null=True` on that field). When you delete it, south needs to know what value do you want to fill in when you recover the field in case you want to reverse the migration.

If you understand south, it has `forward` and `backward` methods, to apply and revert the changes respectively. When you want to undo the migration, your data for field `adress` on model `Content` cannot be recovered. But you already made it not nullable, south needs to fill in some value, hence the prompt message.

The solution depends on your need. If you don't bother recovering the values for that field, pick `3` would be OK, because you will never run backwards migration. Or pick `2` but it doesn't do any better than `3`, just fill in a default value for all records, which is most likely not what you want.

Comment: I see...thanks, is there some why that I can delete the field `adress` in `Content` table ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate a little?